Battery Status Icon Not Updating in Android Notification Bar Despite Kernel and HAL Changes
I am working on an Android project where the battery status icon in the notification bar does not reflect the actual charging or discharging state. While logs confirm that the status is correctly retrieved from the kernel and updated in the HAL, the UI icon remains stuck in the "charging" state.
Here's what I have modified so far:

HAL Modifications (Health.cpp)

batteryStatus = BatteryStatus::CHARGING;
batteryStatus = BatteryStatus::DISCHARGING;
2.** Framework Modifications (BatteryService.java)**
I added logging and updated the getIconLocked method to dynamically select the correct battery icon based on the charging status retrieved from mHealthInfo.
What additional changes are required to ensure that the battery status icon in the notification bar dynamically updates to reflect the current charging state? Could there be an issue with:
1.Propagating the updated battery status from the HAL to the framework?
2.Syncing the framework status with the UI notification bar?
3.Some other subsystem in AOSP controlling the battery status icon?
Any guidance or suggestions to debug this issue further would be greatly appreciated!
